# Libreswan invalid peer id while connecting to ikev1 tunnel

Tags: vpn, ipsec, libreswan

I want to connect to a watchguard remote access vpn server. I got the following shrewsoft configuration file for that:

```
n:version:2
s:network-host:SERVER_IP
n:network-ike-port:500
s:client-auto-mode:pull
s:client-iface:virtual
n:client-addr-auto:1
n:network-mtu-size:1380
s:network-natt-mode:enable
n:network-natt-port:4500
n:network-natt-rate:20
s:network-frag-mode:disable
n:network-dpd-enable:1
n:network-notify-enable:1
n:client-banner-enable:0
n:client-wins-used:1
n:client-wins-auto:1
n:client-dns-used:1
n:client-dns-auto:1
n:client-splitdns-used:1
n:client-splitdns-auto:1
s:auth-method:mutual-psk-xauth
b:auth-mutual-psk:SECRET
s:ident-client-type:ufqdn
s:ident-client-data:USERID
s:ident-server-type:any
s:phase1-exchange:aggressive
s:phase1-cipher:aes
n:phase1-keylen:256
s:phase1-hash:sha2-256
n:phase1-dhgroup:14
n:phase1-life-secs:86400
n:vendor-chkpt-enable:0
s:phase2-transform:esp-aes
n:phase2-keylen:256
s:phase2-hmac:sha2-256
n:phase2-pfsgroup:14
n:phase2-life-secs:28800
n:phase2-life-kbytes:0
s:ipcomp-transform:disabled
s:policy-level:unique
n:policy-nailed:0
n:policy-list-auto:0
s:policy-list-include:192.168.170.89 / 255.255.255.255
```

This just works fine on windows, but on linux without GUI there is a known bug that traffic to the vpn won't get routed.

So I tried using Libreswan to connect, here is my config for that:

```
conn VPN
    authby=secret
    keyexchange=ike
    ikev2=no
    auto=add
    aggressive=yes
    fragmentation=no

    ike=aes256-sha2;modp2048
    phase2=esp
    phase2alg=aes256-sha2;modp2048

    right=SERVER_IP
    left=%defaultroute

    leftid=@USERNAME
    rightid=%any
    rightnexthop=%defaultroute
    rightsubnet=192.168.170.89/32

    leftmodecfgclient=yes
    modecfgpull=yes
    nat-keepalive=yes

    leftxauthclient=yes
    leftxauthusername=XAUTH_USER
    rightxauthserver=yes
```

But I get the following error in phase1:

```
002 "VPN" #1: initiating IKEv1 Aggressive Mode connection
110 "VPN" #1: sent Aggressive Mode request
002 "VPN" #1: Peer ID is ID_IPV4_ADDR: 'NOT_SERVER_IP'
003 "VPN" #1: Peer ID 'NOT_SERVER_IP' mismatched on first found connection and no better connection found
003 "VPN" #1: initial Aggressive Mode packet claiming to be from SERVER_IP on SERVER_IP:500 but no connection has been authorized
218 "VPN" #1: sending notification INVALID_ID_INFORMATION to SERVER_IP:500
```

SERVER_IP refers to the vpn gateway IP and NOT_SERVER_IP refers to some "random" ipv4

As I said, this happens only with libreswan and not with shrewsoft. Is there any common configuration missing?
I even captured the initial ISAKMP request from shrewsoft and libreswan,
[libreswan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIVnF.png)
[shrewsoft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u48yc.png)

**really appreciate any help on this topic**

I tried setting the rightip to the ip provided in the libreswan response, but than I get

```
received Hash Payload does not match computed value
223 "VPN" #1: sending notification INVALID_HASH_INFORMATION to SERVER_IP:500
```

Which should be a result of using the wrong id in the request